# disable all input tags of parentNode -jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dhtml

I need to disable all input tags of parent node of current object

Scenario is like below

question with options

```
 <div class="question_title"> 
      question 1

     <div class="answers"> 
      <div class="optionsa">
       [radiobutton] opt1
     </div>
     <div class="optionsa">
       [radiobutton] opt2
     </div>
    <div class="optionsa">
       [radiobutton] opt3
    </div>
  </div>  
 </div> 

 <div class="question_title"> 
      question 2

     <div class="answers"> 
      <div class="optionsa">
       [radiobutton] opt1
     </div>
     <div class="optionsa">
       [radiobutton] opt2
     </div>
    <div class="optionsa">
       [radiobutton] opt3
    </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
```

now whenever i choose one option of one question it should disable all other options

i did  the following

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".optionsa").click(function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().children().attr('disabled',true);

          });
});
  </script>
```

but it is not working, anything that i missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.closest()` along with `.find()` in this context,

```
 $(".optionsa").click(function(){
     $(this).closest('.question_title').find(':radio').prop('disabled',true);
 });
```

Comment: there could be mutiple div with name 'question title'

Comment: @timus2001 Why does that matter? You only want the one that contains the option you clicked on, that's what `.closest()` does.

Comment: hmm .. let me implement

Comment: The important part is using `.find()` instead of `.children()`, because the radio buttons you want to disable are not immediate children of `.parent().parent()`.